# ngBoilerplate and Font Awesome

Tags: gruntjs, bower, font-awesome, ngboilerplate

I have a ngBoilerplate project, I would like to add Font Awesome to it.
I have installed Font Awesome with:

```
bower install font-awesome --save-dev
```

I then added the following to the `build.config.js` file:

```
css: [
  'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
],
assets: [
  'vendor/font-awesome/fonts/*'
]
```

And I added the following to my `src/less/variables.less` file:

```
@fa-font-path: "../assets";
```

Now I would like to add a simple home icon to my site with:

```
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
```

Instead now I get a ␦ (ascii, blank square) where the icon should be.
The Font Awesome CDN works fine but cant get it to work with bower.

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason I get an intermittent error that the font files cant be found.
I amended the `build.config.js` and removed `'vendor/font-awesome/fonts/*'`.
Then I configured `Gruntfile.js` to copy the fonts to the folder that error was looking for.  I did this by adding the following to the copy section:

```
font_awesome_fonts:  {
        files:{
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          src: 'vendor/font-awesome/fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= build_dir %>/vendor/fonts' 
        }
      }
```

And added the following to the `delta.assets` section:

```
'copy:font_awesome_fonts'
```

This seemed to work but now I get the following warning messages in console, no idea why, at least it works now:

```
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:14080/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:14080/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:14080/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question; it got me on the path to this answer.

What worked for me was using the Font Awesome **LESS** file instead of the **CSS**. In `src/less/main.less` I added the following:

```
@import '../../vendor/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less';
```

I made this declaration in my `src/less/variables.less`:

```
@fa-font-path: ".";
```

I also removed any mention of the font awesome from the vendor css section of `build.config.js`. My font declaration looks a bit different, but should be effectively the same:

```
vendor_files: [
  js: ...,
  css: [
  ],
  assets: [
    'vendor/font-awesome/fonts/*.otf',
    'vendor/font-awesome/fonts/*.eot',
    'vendor/font-awesome/fonts/*.svg',
    'vendor/font-awesome/fonts/*.ttf',
    'vendor/font-awesome/fonts/*.woff'
  ]
]
```

I haven't noticed your issue with the fonts not copying, nor have I seen the messages in the console, but the icons show up correctly when hosting the files in a webserver and browsing to my app.